# ObjectMapper different behaviour in Resteasy Client with proxy

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, resteasy, jackson-databind

I'm doing a quite usual task to integrate a remote JSON service in a spring application,
what it seems to happen is that the ObjectMapper set into a ResteasyJackson2Provider behave differently from the same ObjectMapper used "manually":

```
@Service
public class MyService {

    @Autowired
    ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    public MyItem getItemById(Long itemId) {
        MyServiceClient client = getMyServiceClient("http://localhost:8888/myservice");

        //Not Working
        MyItem item = client.getItem(itemId);
            
        //Working 
        String itemJson = client.getItemJson(itemId);
        MyItem itemFromJson = objectMapper.readValue(itemJson, MyItem.class);
        
        return item;
    }

    private MyServiceClient getMyServiceClient(String serviceUrl) {
        ResteasyJackson2Provider resteasyJacksonProvider = new ResteasyJackson2Provider();
        resteasyJacksonProvider.setMapper(objectMapper);
        ResteasyClient client = new ResteasyClientBuilder().register(resteasyJacksonProvider).build();
        ResteasyWebTarget target = client
                .target(UriBuilder.fromPath(serviceUrl));
        MyServiceClient proxy = target.proxy(MyServiceClient.class);
        return proxy;
    }

}
```

When delegating the deserialisation to the proxy i get this error:

> java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private final int java.time.LocalDate.year accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.time" to unnamed module @13e39c73

And from unit tests I made, this error happens when not including "  .registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());"  in object mapper.

But when I manually call the  objectMapper.readValue()  this does not happens, and the object is correctly deserialised.

here the code of the proxy interface methods:

```
@Path("/api")
public interface MyServiceClient {

    @GET
    @Path("/items/{id}")
    MyItem getItem(@PathParam("id") Long id);

    @GET
    @Path("/items/{id}")
    String getItemJson(@PathParam("id") Long id);
}
```

Comment: It looks like you need to add the `--add-opens=java.base/java.time=ALL-UNNAMED` to your JVM parameters.

Comment: the registered object mapper is configured with JavaTimeModule, and the same data deserialisation done by manually passing the json to the mapper actually works. The problem was that during rest easy call, such objectmapper is not being used

Comment: What version of RESTEasy are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After other tests I did today, the problem is not the objectmapper itself, but is related to the resteasyJacksonProvider and its registration into the client builder.

Since, still don't know why, there's already a module registered of same class in the ResteasyClientBuilder, that second registration is being ignored.

So the instance used for data reading is an empty default mapper.